# Cannot access localhost from Android device

Tags: android, localhost

Emulator can access web service fromlocal host but my real device cannot although I use LAN ip address (192.168.xx.yyy) instead of 10.0.2.2. Of course, my android mobile was recognized by adb and it connected my laptop via usb port.

I already read some similar questions at stackoverflow but still didn't know how to access webservice from a real android mobile. The answer of this question [How can I access my localhost from my Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device) my be useful but i don't really understand that answer.

Anyone helps me? Thanks you!

Comment: try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17603378/1600061

Comment: Though i know it's late but for new people who have a problem like this please see --> 192.168.1.yyy i got this same problem since 192.168.0.yyy is for browser  and 192.168.1.yyy for mobile devices  in my case that resolved everything for me.
Contact your system administrator or ask some senior programmer. Enjoy Programming!

Answer (score 10):

Possibly the web server is listening on the loopback interface but not on the network interface. This means that hits on `127.0.0.1` and `localhost` will work, but `192.168.xxx.xxx` will not (whether from localhost, LAN, or WAN).

To determine which interface the server is listening on, look [here](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/702/lists-all-listening-ports-together-with-the-pid-of-the-associated-process#comment) for a command to tell you about the listening ports (I used `lsof -Pan -i tcp -i udp`). Then look for your server process in the list. For the `lsof` command, if for port 8888 you see something like `TCP *:8888 (LISTEN)` then your server is listening on all interfaces. But if you instead see something like `TCP [::127.0.0.1]:8888 (LISTEN)` then you have identified your problem!

The next step to solve your problem is to set up your server's run configuration to listen on all interfaces. I don't know what server you are using, but if you can specify an IP address, then you may want to try `0.0.0.0`. Usually you can do this near where it lets you specify the listening port. Thus, if you have a configuration like:

`--port 8888`

Then you can try:

`--port 8888 --address 0.0.0.0`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, the below point is more important for developer community

I am not a network expert; like me many developers may be there.

change to 0.0.0.0:80 in httpd.conf is very important.

In normal(default) settings, port 8888 throws error in WAMPSERVER (even in Windows Browser). That is why I explained the exact environment where port 8888 throws error.

Specific information about what configuration throws error and what configuration works successfully is more important.

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried using a wifi router which is connected to your LAN? Then you just need to connect to the wifi using your mobile and you should be able to access (192.168.xx.yyy)

Comment: I already tried. I unpluged usb cable and connected mobile to to same LAN as laptop(Now my mobile and laptop have the same IP) but i still counld not access webservice from mobile.

Comment: Can you access the web service from a different machine? do you need to mention a port number? Is a firewall blocking access to the webservice?

Comment: Different machines in the same LAN cannot too. I don't know why huh

Comment: Ok. Make sure the webservice is running? ensure the port number, check the iss config. also check if firewall is blocking the ports. Once you get it working and you can access the webservice from different machines,  you will be able to access it from your android device.

Comment: Of course the webservice is running (i can access it from emulator). The webservice, i just Ctrl-F5 from Visual Studio 2010 and it started webservice, no iss. Firewall already turned off. But i still could not access webservice from a real device :(

Comment: You mean **192.168.xx.yyy**. It is confusing for someone that does not know