# Accessing localhost of PC from USB connected Android mobile device

Tags: android

I have an android device (Samsung galaxy tab) connected to my PC via USB .

I want to use WebServices and run a web page which is located on my local xampp server of my PC on my android device .

I can achieve it if I have both , my PC and android device , connected on the same wireless network .

However is it possible to access the localhost page without any wireless connection , using only USB connection .

(PS : This same scenario works when I run the app on an emulator and use the ip 10.0.2.2 to access the localhost on my PC)

Comment: Please use the below link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device]  

It worked for me.

Comment: Turn off the firewall while testing your webpage or add your ip to the trusted networks in the firewall settings.

Comment: check out this blog https://mycodingchannel.in/blog/access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device/ for detail

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I finally solved this problem. I used Samsung Galaxy S with Froyo. The "port" below is the same port what you use for the emulator (10.0.2.2:port). 
What I did:

1. first connect your real device with the USB cable (make sure you can upload the app on your device)
2. get the IP address from the device you connect, which starts with 192.168.x.x:port
3. open the "Network and Sharing Center"
4. click on the "Local Area Connection" from the device and choose "Details"
5. copy the "IPv4 address" to your app and replace it like: `http://192.168.x.x:port/test.php`
6. upload your app (again) to your real device
7. go to properties and turn "USB tethering" on
8. run your application on the device

It should now work.

Comment: If I do this, I get an unknown host exception.

Comment: It seems this answer, while it works, assumes that the Android device and computer are both connected to a wireless access point which is contrary to what the author is trying to achieve.

Comment: It should be noted that this is a Windows only solution.

Comment: I agree with @Jacob, this doesn't answer the question. The question itself states that he can connect over wifi.

Comment: This does not answer the question. This is the right answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53920173/2947592

Answer (score 70):

Google posted a solution for this kind of problem [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server).

The steps:

- Connect your Android device and your development machine with USB debugging enabled
- Open Chrome in your development machine, open new tab, right click in the new browser tab, click inspect
- Click the three dots icon on right top side [image: three dots], -> More Tools, Remote Devices.
- Look at bottom of the screen, make sure your device name is appeared on the list with Green colored dot.
- Look below at the settings part, check the **Port forwarding** mark
- Add rule. Example, if your python web server is running on your machine localhost:5000 and you want to access it from your device port 3333, you type `3333` on the left part, and type `localhost:5000`, and click add rule.
- Voila, now you can access your web server from your device. Try open new browser tab, and visit http://localhost:3333 from your device

Update:

> "This panel has been deprecated in favor of the
> chrome://inspect/#devices interface, which has equivalent
> functionality."

So just paste chrome://inspect/#devices in chrome and skip to the Port forwarding step of the answer.

Comment: Works as advertised. Also keep the ports on device and machine the same is possible:). (Not sure why you want to use another port on the device)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. If you're using a self-signed cert for your local dev remember to add the SSL protocol in New tab e.g https://localhost:5000. It works perfectly.

Comment: _"This panel has been deprecated in favor of the chrome://inspect/#devices interface, which has equivalent functionality."_
So just paste `chrome://inspect/#devices` in chrome and skip to the *Port forwarding* step of the answer.

Comment: I just spent over an hour trying to figure out how to get these instructions to work with `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` coming back from Chrome on the device...until I finally realized that I wasn't running my localhost server on my desktop and that there was nothing to actually connect to!  Doh!  Started the server (Apache in this case) and everything immediately started to function.  An important first step is to make sure your destination server is actually running before setting up the port forward.

Comment: this is the best solution

Comment: The right answer is *port forwarding*. Normally you would set this up in your firewall - either with the config text file or with some app like Icefloor. But the process can be a little involved for people who don't deal with firewall configs regularly. So Chrome dev tools gives the easy way to set it up with a simple GUI. I had port forwarding set up manually a couple years back on a different machine, and I still feel lazy to do it all over again.

Answer (score 21):

I've read numerous forums and tried play apps but not found a solution until now.

My scenario I believe is similar to yours, but I will clarify to help others. I have a locally hosted website and web services to be used by my android application. I need to have this working on the road for demonstration with only my laptop and no network connection.

**Note:** Using my iPhone as a wifi hotspot and connecting both my pc and my android device worked, but the iPhone 4S connection is slow and dropped out regularly.

**My solution is as follows:**

- Unplug network cables on PC and turn off wifi.
- Turn off wifi on android device
- Connect android to pc via USB
- Turn on "USB Tethering" in the android menu. (Under networks->more...->Tethering and portable hotspot")
- Get the IP of your computer that has been assigned by the USB tether cable. (open command prompt and type "ipconfig" then look for the IP that the USB network adapter has assigned)
- Open a browser on the PC using the IP address found instead of localhost to test. i.e. `http://192.168.1.1/myWebSite`
- Open a browser on the android and test it works

Comment: I have Nexus 10 and I'm unable to make it works for me but I desperately need it. No tethering option!?

Comment: I have a problem too in moto g5s plus. I assign is still not work.

Answer (score 7):

I did this on a windows computer and it worked perfectly!

Turn on USB Tethering in your mobile.
Type ipconfig in the command prompt in your computer and find the ipv4 for "ethernet adapter local area connection x" (mostly the first one)
Now go to your mobile browser, type that ipv4 with the port number of your web application. eg:- 192.168.40.142:1342

It worked with those simple steps!

Answer (score 6):

1. Make sure you have [adb installed on the computer](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb), [USB debugging enabled on the phone](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options), and the phone has allowed access to the computer.  Plug the phone into the computer via USB cable, and make sure it's visible (it should show up in the Bash command `adb devices`.
2. **In your computer's Chrome browser, open chrome://inspect/#devices**, click the "Port forwarding" button, check "Enable port forwarding", and add the port on the computer that you want to be accessible from the phone ([detailed instructions here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/local-server#port-forwarding)).  You'll need to keep open the tab running chrome://inspect/#devices.
3. In your phone's browser, navigate to localhost:[port_number], and it should display whatever is running on the computer.

This works on Windows and Ubuntu Linux, and should work on Mac as well.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a piece of my Android app's code:

This app is able to communicate with a HTTP get-post model between ***a servlet*** running on a server and ***an Android device*** plugged in USB-Debuggable mode (*because the app was in developing progress*).

I also can run the app over Wi-Fi when the server, Tomcat Apache 7, running on (*when the app development was finished*).

[image]

To get the IP address of yours

1. Go to Command Prompt
2. Type `ipconfig`
3. Hit enter

In the list, ***IPv4 Address***  is your IP.

Comment: This is inaccurate.  USB debuggable mode does not provide a network connection, nor will ADB forwards allow the device to contact the PC.  By appearances, you are using a network connection over USB likely provided by a tethering tool, not USB debugging.  Another option is to tunnel ssh through an ADB forward.

Comment: I didn't mean that usb-debugable mode provides a network connection. But unfortunately, that was the only way to perform some internal commands coming from an android app project to the web server embedded to the Android Studio. Thanks for your concern, it migth be confusing for fresh developers. Editted as the app in developing progress in Android Studio.

Comment: There is still no *answer* here providing a method to achieve connectivity in this direction.  "USB-debuggable mode" doesn't do that, so without an *accurate* description of how you did it, **there is no solution here**.

Answer (score 4):

How to Easily access LocalHost in Actual Android Device -> Connect your pc with the android device via USB

1. Go to Chrome inspection click 'f12' or Control+Shift+C

[Chrome Inspection tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrM1p.png)

2. Check the bottom of the chrome inspection tool.
3. Now go to settings in Remote Device Tab.

[Remote Devices Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUW8C.png)

4. check on "Discover USB Device" option as well as check on "Port Forwarding" option.
5. Now Click on Add Rules, Enter Any Device Port e.g(4880) and in Local Address Enter the Actual Address of the local host in my case e.g (127.0.0.1:480)
6. After Adding the Rule go to your android studio -> inside your code URL(http://127.0.0.1:4880). Remember to change the port from 480 -> 4880.
7. Go to Remote Device Tab in Chrome and Click on your connected Device. Add New URL(127.0.0.1:4880)
   [Inspect the Android Device Chrome Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijoo7.png)

Check your Actual Device Chrome Browser and start Debugging the code on Actual Android device.

Answer (score 2):

Zsivics Sanel's [answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17603378/15092122) work fine for USB Debugging but if you want to access your localhost on device  for **Wifi ADB** you can use command
`adb reverse tcp:port tcp:port`
and use the link `http://localhost:port/` on your android to access the `http://localhost:port/` of your pc.

- This works for **USB Debugging** as well :)

The detailed answer with explaination is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46795769/15092122).

Answer (score 1):

Check for the USB connection type options. You should have one called "Internet pass through". That will let your phone use the same connection as your PC.

Comment: That's the only way I know of to use the PC's connection via USB. So for your device I guess the answer is no. The simulator works because it shares your PC's connection.

Comment: I know new HTC devices with Sense 3 have the option (Ex the Sensation)

Comment: thanks a lot for the help . still to check if any of the options work .

Answer (score 1):

I very much liked John's answer, but I'd like to give it with some changes to those that want to test some client//server configuration by running a client TCP on the USB connected Mobile and a server on the local PC.

First it's quite obvious that the 10.0.2.2 won't work because this is a REAL hardware mobile and not a simulator.

So Follow John's instructions:

- Unplug all network cables on PC and turn off wifi.
- Turn off wifi on the android device
- Connect android device to pc via USB
- Turn on the "USB Tethering" (USB Modem/ USB Cellular Modem / USB שימוש כמודם סלולרי) in the android menu. (Under networks->more...->Tethering and portable hotspot")

  - This USB connection will act as a DHCP server for you single PC connection, so it'll assign your PC a dedicated (dynamic) IP in its local USB network. Now all you have to do is tell the client application this IP and port.
- Get the IP of your PC (that has been assigned by the USB tether cable.) 
  (open command prompt and type "ipconfig" then look for
  the IP that the USB network adapter has assigned, in Linux its `ifconfig` or Ubuntu's "Connection information" etc..)
- Tell the application to connect to that IP (i.e. 192.168.42.87) with something like (Java - client side):

  ```
  String        serverIP      = "192.168.42.87";
  int           serverPort    = 5544;
  InetAddress   serverAddress = InetAddress.getByName(serverIP);
  Socket        socket         = new Socket(serverAddress, serverPort);
  ...
  ```

  Enjoy..

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can access your xampp localhost by

1. Control panel -->
2. windows defender firewall -->
3. Advance setting (on left side) --> Inbound Rules --> New Rule --> Port --> in specific local port write your Apache ports --> next --> next 
   then you can access your localhost by using local PC IP address:

Answer (score 0):

Connecting android phone via USB cable and accessing http server on the Computer.

1. Firewall - switch it off, once everything works you can add a rule
   under Inbound rules, enable Apache HTTP Server (UDP and TCP) (or whatever HTTP server you're using) *Warning - if you switch off the firewall, your computer becomes vulnerable to internet attacks. So switch off internet and disconnect from network first.* You don't need to be on the Internet for this to work, as you're connecting two devices on local network.
2. Plug in the USB cable. If networking window pops up, select Home Network. If it doesn't pop up it's probably set to Public (which won't work), so go to: Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center (in win7) and set it to Home Network there. It might give you a next screen after you press it to share Pictures, Music... just click cancel on it. On the main screen Home Network will still be active.
3. You need the Computer's IP, localhost or other aliases don't work. To get the IP of your machine, start the Windows command line shell (press Windows Key + R and type cmd), the black command prompt window should pop up, type: "ipconfig" and hit enter. Now look for

IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.###.###
That's the IP that your phone assigned to your computer

4. Now you should be done, in the phone's browser, try accessing a test html file from your computer's server it should display fine.
5. Now that everything is working you'll probably want to enable the firewall and Internet access on your computer. Now try accessing your http server again. It probably won't work. Depending on your setup you might get a popup asking you to add a rule to allow it, but if you don't, just add it yourself. Start the windows firewall and go to Inbound Rules (because it's a server) and add New Rule. Select "Program". Locate the exe of your http server, and in the next screen make sure Allow is selected. Try connecting again, and now it should work. If not it's probably because you selected wrong exe. You can even go more advanced to restrict outside usage (because now everyone on the internet can access it if they have your Internet IP address) To restrict access you can right-click on the new rule you've just created, click Properties, and go to Scope tab and change things there accordingly.

   Note for Android developers, now in your android code, you have to use "http://", otherwise it won't work. For example: MyAsyncTask.execute("http://192.168.123.123/test.html")

**Part II -- Setting IP to fixed/static.**

Now that things work, every time you unplug the cable and plug it back in, your IP will change. And if you are using it somewhere like inside a code, you'll have to update it every time! Solution I've come up with is to set the IP to static.

1. Having the phone connected and tethered, go back to Network and Sharing Center and click on the Local Area connection "Connections:"

[image: screenshot]

2. On the next screen select Properties, then highlight IP 4 and press properties there and click "Use the following IP address"
3. Put Default Gateway and Subnet Mask exactly as it was in the ipconfig, and for the IP Address, only change the last 3 digits to anything from 1 to 255

[image: screenshot]

That IP will be your new fixed/static IP and it will remain the same next time you plug the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Problem I faced maybe it will help some one, I was working long time where my pc and android device connected to the same WiFi network and the android device connected via the IPV4 address of the pc with opened port 8080 trought the fire wall.

ONE DAY :
I installed Genymotion emulator in order to debug UI on different screens.
THANKS to Genymotion/Virtualbox network configurations it ruined my WiFi adapter.

The fix was to reconfigure IPV4/TCP settings on the WiFi netwrok adapter :

[image]