# How to access a webservice running on a Win7 PC from an unrooted Android device via USB?

Tags: android, web-services, usb

I have a use case where my app running on an Android device needs to communicate with a web service running on a Win7 PC. This was achieved using Wi-Fi succesfully. But now I need to achieve this using a USB connection as we may not have Wi-Fi working at customer place.

The Android device is unrooted. I can not use "Reverse Tethering App" as it needs the device to be rooted.

The following link has the same question but not having any answer:

[Accessing localhost of PC from USB connected Android mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887621/accessing-localhost-of-pc-from-usb-connected-android-mobile-device)

Does anybody have aa answer for this?

Comment: "The following link has the same question but not having any answer." -> flagged duplicate

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing localhost of PC from USB connected Android mobile device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887621/accessing-localhost-of-pc-from-usb-connected-android-mobile-device)

Comment: You can do that using adb port forwarding method.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this before.  Try this:

- On your Android device enabled USB debugging

  - Android 3.2 or older, you can find the option under Settings > Applications > Development.
  - On Android 4.0 and newer, it's in Settings > Developer options.
- On your Android device open the browser and visit `http://192.168.2.2`  (this assumes your web services is on port 80)