# Sending push notification using localhost

Tags: android

Is it possible to send push notification to android app using php in localhost without external cloud like GCM and Parse.

If yes, how can I do it?

Comment: you can create local host server..check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887621/accessing-localhost-of-pc-from-usb-connected-android-mobile-device) and create service to fetch data for there and generate notification in device....

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to send from localhost with php but GCM is required. You will notify to GCM with notification data and registered ids and GCM will notify the clients.