# Persistent Unknown Host Exception When using Apache Http Client

Tags: java, android, asynchttpclient

I'm currently using localhost to develop mobile apps in android studio while connecting via a USB cable. I set up the localhost environment using this method https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539795/4681900 and got it to work on an IP address. The problem is I keep getting `Unknown Host Exception`s when trying to make a `HTTP` call. Sometimes the connection works fine but most times it fails.

Here is a sample code

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("https://192.xxx.xxx.xxx", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Awesome",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, 
       Throwable e) {
       if(errorResponse==null){
           Toast.makeText(getContext(),"No response",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
           return;
       }
       Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error connecting",Toast.LENGHT_SHORT).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onRetry(int retryNo) {
    }
});
```

Here is part of the exception's stack trace

```
01-26 08:29:34.103 3789-4880/com.foodplace W/System.err: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "my-PC": No address associated with hostname
```

How can this be fixed? I am using `Async Http Client` (http://loopj.com/android-async-http/) and `WAMP` as my localhost server.

Comment: Can you connect to the address using a browser?

Comment: Yes.The browser can connect to the address.That's why I'm stuck

Comment: From the error, it's trying to resolve `my-PC` as a hostname.  Is that specified anywhere in your code?  And in which line of code is the error occurring?