# Cannot access localhost from android connected via usb with wamp

Tags: android, localhost, usb, desktop

I have followed the steps given in [Accessing localhost of PC from USB connected Android mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887621/accessing-localhost-of-pc-from-usb-connected-android-mobile-device)

But now I am coming up with an error. Please take a look at the screenshots

This image is showing that localhost has started interaction with my browser on mobile but it is showing an error that I don't have permission to access through the server

[image: fytgj]

This is the screenshot of the ipconfig screen on cmd prompt along with wamp open and online

[image: sdfgdg]

Please help me with this.

Answer (score -1):

You have to change httpd.conf settings to allow access from other device.