# Shall I connect my localhost web service from android without network?

Tags: android, web-services, networking, localhost, ip-address

I have running my web service in localhost. I want to call this web service from my android mobile. I'm testing the application from android studio with the mobile. I don't have router or modem. I have connected internet from mobile wifi hotspot. I can't call web service which is running on my localhost using ipaddress from mobile. what should I do?

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Mighe be helpful this answer [Accessing localhost of PC from USB connected Android mobile device](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26539795/7589424)

Comment: .`I can't call web service which is running on my localhost using ipaddress from mobile. ` You should be able to do so if your PC is connected wirelessly to your mobile hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

you have to check your firewall settings in your computer