# Not able to access rails server from phone

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, server

I have a rails server running on my machine. I am running the server using the following command:

```
rails s -b my_computer_ip
```

Now, I am trying to access the server on my phone's browser using the following command

```
http://my_computer_ip:3000
```

but I keep getting: "The site cannot be reached"

Both my phone and computer are connected over the same network.

I have tried following options:

```
rails s -b 0.0.0.0 (On computer)
http://192.168.1.80:3000 (On phone)
```

But do not work.

Earlier I used to connect to server on my phone in the same way I have mentioned but I don't understand what issue is now cropping up.

PS: When I do the following:

```
 http://my_computer_ip
```

on my phone's browser, I get the page saying Apache server is running.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9887621/accessing-localhost-of-pc-from-usb-connected-android-mobile-device

This will help you. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a networking concept error. You have to enable the port `3000` in your router. Instead, try running the server on port `80`, your firewall is probably blocking port `3000`.

Comment: Yes you are right. The issue got solved with the following command:
sudo ufw allow 3000