# How do I run an Android app on a real device?

Tags: android, node.js, xampp

I'm working with a nodejs, mysql, Android stack.

I want to test my android app on real device and connected my laptop and     mobile on same WIFI network and specified the IP address in URL as I'm using Volley library

url is:
http://ipaddress:8080
**8080 is nodejs server port**

But when i run my android app it does not run on nodejs server.No request is processed on nodejs server though request is sent from android side

I have tried many links but none of them worked.
Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is your device and server in same network?

Comment: yes my device and server laptop is connected to same WIFI network

Comment: Have you tried disabling firewall?

Comment: no i didn't....

Comment: Try disabling firewall and then check if connection works.

Comment: Also check if Chrome browser can access the URL.

Comment: disabling firewall doesn't works and chrome browser is not able to access URL.It is not navigating to phpmyadmin instead it is showing **cannot GET/**

Comment: You should resolve your server issues first. And once you will be able to access your server at least from chrome browser, then you should try your app.

Comment: @primo looks like issue with your server. check if its working properly on your Laptop first

Comment: i tried using different method connecting laptop to mobile's WIFI hotspot and it worked for me and when i run its URL on browser then also it is showing me same error ** cannot GET/**..so,this might not be the issue as on same 8080 port i am accessing its html side also

Comment: `It is not navigating to phpmyadmin ` ??? Why should it navigate to phpadmin? It should connect with your node.js server. You should use a Chrome or other browser running on your Android device to test. It is unclear which ip-address you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I have the answer to my question
I tried the following link and it worked for me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17603378/8101634

what it states is.
1) Connecting android device through USB cable to laptop
2) Switching USB tethering on android device
3) Go to network and sharing center.
4) It will show you the device and click on it.
5) Click on details
6) Take the Ipv4 address from there and use it as URL in android app
7) Re-run your android application

It works
```

Comment: Bad solution. You should not need a cable. Or make the Android device a hotspot. Just using the ip of your pc should do it.

Comment: if it should not be connected using USB cable then how will i launch my application on my device..

Comment: Well during development and if your IDE wants to install your apk you need a cable indeed. But then you should not start usb tethering. Just a normal wifi connection should do. If your apk runs then you dont wanna connect your phone the whole time to a pc is it?

Comment: for sometime it will show proper data to me if i disconnect USB from pc after application launch..

Comment: and i used usb tethering as my both devices were connected on same WIFI network but then also request was not reaching upto the node server

Comment: You should try to resolve that problem using wifi. First try a browser on your pc. If that goes ok a browser on your device. Tell us which ip exactly you use when using a browser on your device.

Comment: i use 192.168.x.x:8080

Comment: And that is the ip of ... the server ?? Please be exact. You should not use the ip of the client. You can safely publish the whole ip as millions of computers in this world have that ip.