# Access the localhost via android device Easyphp

Tags: android, windows, mobile, localhost, wifi

I need to access a localhost on easyphp via a physical android device, but I'm not succeeding.

I tried to disable firewalls, both private and public, but nothing.

I tried using the ipv4 of the wireless wifi lan card, but nothing.

I've tried various solutions on stackoverflow, but nothing seems to work.

- Os pc: windows 8.1
- port localhost: 8080
- Nodejs

I'm doing the tests from the mozilla browser of the android device.
Can it be a problem?

What can I do?

Comment: Did you tried http://your-pc-ip-adress/phpMyAdmin ??

Comment: if you are using emulator then write 10.0.2.2 instead of localhost

Comment: @E.Abdel: To access phpmyadmin, I have to do something like this:
http: // localhost / modules / phpmyadmin414x150111040152 /

Comment: @WaleedAsim: physical android device.

Comment: replace localhost by the local IP adress of your PC, example 192.168.1.25

Comment: @Paul go to cmd write ipconfig then copy ip address and paste it over localhost

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4779963/how-can-i-access-my-localhost-from-my-android-device

Answer (score 2):

Use a fixed ip of server machine rather then local host.
and your mobile device and server machine having same network, like local network.
like:

**your.ip.address:port/yourpath**

Comment: try to use static ip set on server then check on android device.

Answer (score 0):

try this method -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/56884341/8168420

I use localhost:4880 in your Case just put the "local address" -> localhost:8080 in the port forward and the Device port will be any port of your choice e.g (8888)