# Localhost restAPI access from Android Studios on physical device using cable

Tags: flutter, api, android-studio, localhost, android-networking

I have created an API in DjangoREST,and it is running on my localhost with address http://localhost:xxxxx/api/allproduct.

I have also created an Android app in Futter, using Android Studio and tried to access the above API. I am debugging my app using data cable (Not by emulator). I am not able to access the API.
I must test the application with cable not on emulator, any leads please.

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/q/9887621/11617436

Answer (score 1):

I use a proxy service called [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/). After installing, you can run it like:

`ngrok http 8080` (assuming your localhost is serving on port 8080)

It will create a tunnel, both that'll work for both HTTP and HTTPS (so iOS devices don't reject the request, due to an insecure protocol)

Then, you just need to replace your `http://localhost` with the host from ngrok, that will look something like this:

`http://xxxx-xxxx-xxx-...-xxxx.ngrok.io`

It will even give you a web interface that you can go to, to review traffic:

`http://127.0.0.1:4040`

Comment: This would mean that you need to setup ports on routers everywhere you work from right?