# Get method in xamarin.Android REST service

Tags: c#, android, rest, api, xamarin.android

I want to get data from my api usign GetStringAsync Method in my xamarin.android app, but get  error below:

```
System.Net.WebException: Error: ConnectFailure (Connection refused)
```

my code:

```
private static async void MainAsync()
{
     HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:57558/");
     var getResponse = await client.GetStringAsync("/api/home");

     var getTask = client.GetStringAsync("/api/home");
     await getTask.ContinueWith((antecidentTask) =>
     {
         var result = antecidentTask.Result;
     });
}
```

Comment: can you connect to http://localhost:57558/ ? also you are running through android emulator ?

Comment: @Moudiz I can access data typing this url (`http://localhost:57558/api/home`) in my browser. I run app on my android device, not on emulator.

Comment: check this so answer might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131658/xamarin-connect-to-locally-hosted-web-service

Comment: @Moudiz  thanks alot, prolem was about using localhost

Comment: you are welcome