# Get the TCP error 10061 when using web service in an application

Tags: c#, post, get, postman

i'm new in web services, i have created a web service that works fine using postman, i can make requests and see the response, however if i use the same url with the same verb in an application, i get the following error: 
[error 10061 connection refused](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDCgX.png)

the code that makes the call for the service is:

```
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strUrl);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                string json = "{\"user\":\"test\"," +
                              "\"password\":\"bla\"}";

                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
```

what´s missing?

Update:
this is an image with the succesfull response in postman
[Get Verb with json body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ISI25.png)

[Post Verb with json body, just as is in code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbf79.png)

What would be the problem?

Thank's in advance

SOLVED, i've found solution here:
[Xamarin: Connect to locally hosted web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131658/xamarin-connect-to-locally-hosted-web-service)

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make HTTP POST web request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4015324/how-to-make-http-post-web-request)

Comment: Thanks Lutti Coelho, but the problem is not the verb, no matter which ona i use always get the connection refused error, i've added new images that show how in postman the response is successfull, and in the code i get error.

Comment: Can you share the URL you are trying to post?