# System.Net.WebException in android xamarin application

Tags: c#, sql-server, xamarin.android, asmx

I am creating a simple login android application via Xamarin. I made an asmx web service with a login method that checks if a user exists in the database found in SQL Server and hosted it on IIS server. I tried accessing it through my phone's browser and everything went okay. then I created my app and added the web service as a web reference. but when I deployed my android app on my phone this exception occurred.

> I enabled the Internet property for my application.

the details of the exception are as follows:

> {System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: An exception occurred
>   during the operation, making the result invalid.  Check InnerException
>   for exception details. ---> System.Net.WebException: Error:
>   ConnectFailure (No route to host) --->
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No route to host   at
>   System.Net.Sockets.SocketAsyncResult.CheckIfThrowDelayedException ()
>   [0x00014] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/SocketAsyncResult.cs:127
>   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) [0x0002c] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/Socket.cs:1211    at System.Net.Sockets.SocketTaskExtensions+<>c.b__2_1
>   (System.IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net.Sockets/SocketTaskExtensions.cs:36
>   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory`1[TResult].FromAsyncCoreLogic
>   (System.IAsyncResult iar, System.Func`2[T,TResult] endFunction,
>   System.Action`1[T] endAction, System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult]
>   promise, System.Boolean requiresSynchronization) [0x00019] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/external/corert/src/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Threading/Tasks/FutureFactory.cs:538
>
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>
> at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.WebOperation
>   operation, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   [0x00151] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:169
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.Net.WebConnection.Connect (System.Net.WebOperation operation,
>   System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x00217] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:188
>   at System.Net.WebConnection.InitConnection (System.Net.WebOperation
>   operation, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>   [0x000cc] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebConnection.cs:259
>   at System.Net.WebOperation.Run () [0x00052] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebOperation.cs:268
>   at System.Net.WebCompletionSource`1[T].WaitForCompletion () [0x0008e]
>   in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/WebCompletionSource.cs:111
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.RunWithTimeoutWorker[T]
>   (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] workerTask, System.Int32
>   timeout, System.Action abort, System.Func`1[TResult] aborted,
>   System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource cts) [0x000e8] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:956
>   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream (System.IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult) [0x00019] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System/System.Net/HttpWebRequest.cs:901
>   at
>   System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.AsyncGetRequestStreamDone
>   (System.IAsyncResult ar) [0x0000c] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/System.Web.Services/System.Web.Services.Protocols/SoapHttpClientProtocol.cs:118
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---   at System.ComponentModel.AsyncCompletedEventArgs.RaiseExceptionIfNecessary
>   () [0x00008] in
>   /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2019-08/android/release/mcs/class/referencesource/System/compmod/system/componentmodel/AsyncCompletedEventArgs.cs:60
>   at newapplogin.selling.LoginCompletedEventArgs.get_Result () [0x00001]
>   in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Solution1\newapplogin\Web
>   References\selling\Reference.cs:178    at
>   newapplogin.MainActivity.Ws_LoginCompleted (System.Object sender,
>   newapplogin.selling.LoginCompletedEventArgs e) [0x00001] in
>   C:\Users\User\source\repos\Solution1\newapplogin\MainActivity.cs:62
>   at newapplogin.selling.WebService1.OnLoginOperationCompleted
>   (System.Object arg) [0x00016] in
>   C:\Users\User\source\repos\Solution1\newapplogin\Web
>   References\selling\Reference.cs:102    at
>   Android.App.SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass3_0.b__0 () [0x00000]
>   in <11f101b564894ca7af6c482ddc51c698>:0    at
>   Java.Lang.Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run () [0x00008] in
>   <11f101b564894ca7af6c482ddc51c698>:0    at
>   Java.Lang.IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr
>   native__this) [0x00009] in <11f101b564894ca7af6c482ddc51c698>:0    at
>   (wrapper dynamic-method)
>   Android.Runtime.DynamicMethodNameCounter.15(intptr,intptr)}   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

this is my android mainactivity code:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Widget;
using System;
using Xamarin.Essentials;
using Xamarin.Android;
using Android.Content;

namespace newapplogin
{
    [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState); 
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            // Get our button from the layout resource,

            // and attach an event to it

            Button bulogin = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.bulogin);

            Button buRegister = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.buRegister);



            //buRegister.Click += BuRegister_Click;

            bulogin.Click += Bulogin_Click;


        }
        private void Bulogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {

            var etUsername = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etUsername);

            var etPassword = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.etPassword);

            selling.WebService1 ws = new selling.WebService1();
            ws.LoginAsync(etUsername.Text, etPassword.Text);
            ws.LoginCompleted += Ws_LoginCompleted;



        }



        private void Ws_LoginCompleted(object sender, selling.LoginCompletedEventArgs e)

        {



            if (e.Result.ValidUser)

            {

                Toast.MakeText(getApplicationContext(), "successful", 0).Show();



            }

            else


            {
                Toast.MakeText(getApplicationContext(), "failed", 0).Show();

            }

        }

        private Context getApplicationContext()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

and this is my webservice code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;



namespace WebApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for WebService1
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class WebService1 : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public Result Login(string userName, string userPass)
        {
            SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection (new DBConnection().ConnectionString);
            Result result = new Result();
            try
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT username, password FROM people where CONVERT(VARCHAR, username)=@username and CONVERT(VARCHAR, password)=@password");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("username", userName);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("password", userPass);
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                if (conn.State==System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    conn.Open();
                }
                SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (dr.HasRows)
                {
                    result.ValidUser = true;
                    return result;
                }
                else
                {
                    result.ValidUser = false;

                }

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                result.Error = ex.ToString();

            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
            return result;
        }

    }
}
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: What is your Android deivce version? If you use Android 9.0 or above and use http to connect the DB, you should add `<uses-library android:name="org.apache.http.legacy" android:required="false" />` in `application` tag of `AndroidManifest.xml`, If not, can you share a demo that could reproduce this issue.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT the android version on my phone is Android 10. yes sure i'll add my webservice and android code.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT I've edited my question to add my codes.

Comment: Based on your error message, there are two possible reasons, Android Emulator has a different address http://10.0.2.2:your_port that points to 127.0.0.1:your_port on your host machine, If your web services is hosted by IIS Express, you can not access it, you can refer to this thread:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31131658/xamarin-connect-to-locally-hosted-web-service

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT actually sir I hosted my webservice on iis server. I tried reaching it from my phone's browser and it worked well. the web reference that I added to the android app has the following link: http://192.168.0.107/newtrial/webservice1.asmx where the ip address is my laptop's ip, and my phone is in the same network. I tried turning off my firewall on the laptop but I still get the same exception.

Comment: Can you change  192.168.0.107 to 10.0.2.2 to make a test?

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT thanks a lot sir. problem solved. I figured out that my laptop's ip was dynamic and changing so I put it as static. but know I have another issue. I need to be capable of working even if my phone isn't in the same network as my laptop and even if I was using the mobile data instead of wifi. how can I do so. I read that I have to buy a windows web hosting and host my webservice on it. is it the only way? and where could I actually buy this?

Comment: If you have solved this issue, please post your solution to answers, If you have another question(this issue is not related to the xamarin, it is related to network), you can open a new thread for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

the problem was with my ip. it was changing because it was set to be dynamic. so whenever my app tries to access the webservice, it doesn't find it. so I just set my laptop's ip to be static and problem was solved. thanks for your help

Comment: If you have solve this issue, please do not forget to mark it as answer after three days.